# how to hidden the background color using css3

Tags: html, css

I have tried to implement yellow background '' but it's not hiding the yellow background on right side curve? pls suggest me how to hide the right side yellow background which is overflowing on the curve background.

HTML:

```css
.header {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.header-background {
  background: #1d637d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.header-content1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-content>p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-background"></div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    </p>
    <div class="header-content1">
      <p>Click</p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the `header-content1` equal to the content or should it look like a button?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h7uxv4y7/1/ is this what you were looking for

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan, it's like separate block with yellow color

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```css
.header {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.header-background {
    background: #1d637d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.header-content1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header-content > p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-background"></div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    </p>
  <div class="header-content1">
    <p>Click</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i'm increasing the "<div class="header-content">" block contents, the yellow is overflowing, i want to adopt the content into the curve design.